# Camel idiom to route dynamically based on the value in the body of the message

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel, idioms

Suppose you have a route like:

```
from("direct:start").to("http://some.endpoint/accounts/");
```

where message passed through `direct:start` is an XML:

```
<payload>
    <account id="1">Bob</account>
</payload>
```

What's the idiomatic way to extract the account's `id` and append it to the `to` endpoint in order to send this message to `http://some.endpoint/accounts/1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this FAQ about dynamic **to**
http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

Comment: I'm trying it out with the seda endpoint and it keeps failing
    from('seda:input').to('seda:${in.header.output}')
All I get is an exception that "No endpoint could be found for: ${in.header.output}". Any clue on how to get it to work?

Comment: Btw - tested it with "direct" endpoints and it also doesn't work. I'm using Camel 2.8.3 as well as 2.9.0-RC1

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [recipient list](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) pattern to create dynamic endpoints based on Exchange data.

```
from("direct:start")
.recipientList(constant("http://some.endpoint/accounts/")
              .append(XPathBuilder.xpath("/payload/account/@id", String.class)));
```